# tr [a-z] [A-Z] shows error in unix

Tags: unix, tr

In unix, the line `echo "abc" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]` shows following error:

```
    tr: extra operand `b'
    Try tr --help' for more information.
```

It does not show error and prints the correct output `ABC` if it is run from any other directory in the same server or in any other server. Inside a particular directory it shows the above error.
I verified and found no such conflicting file or script. No script exists having the name `tr`.
`which tr` command inside the directory as well as outside the directory gives the same output `/usr/bin/tr`.
In the place of `tr`, I even tried as `echo "abc" | /usr/bin/tr [a-z] [A-Z]` to avoid any confliction with other files, if any. But the same error persists.
And if I try `echo "abc" | tr 'a' 'B'`, it produces the output as `Bbc`. I am not able to figure out the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tr` doesn't need brackets:

```
tr a-z A-Z
```

`[a-z]` have special meaning for your shell (expanded to a list of matching file name). There is probably a matching file (or several matching files) in a directory where it does not work.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me. But I got surprised because the script having such a line worked properly when run a month ago. But it showed the error now. Might be your second line is the answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `[:upper:]` `[:lower:]` to aviod ambiguous filename and expression.

> echo "abc" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]

Answer (score 0):

yes it is correct, `tr [a-z]` other than conversion it will look for a file name starting from `a` to `z` in that case `[a-z]` convert to that file

go to user home directory and look for file name like

```
ls -lrth 

-rw-r--r--   1 root         root          1.5M Aug  3 11:02 a
```

rename it

```
mv a a_backup
```